# Retorno inesperado en un método recursivo

Tags: java, recursión

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio de recursividad en Java. Se trata de realizar un método que reciba como parámetro un número de la secuencia Fibonacci, y me devuelva la posición del mismo (en la secuencia).
No se por qué me devuelve el valor del parámetro que le indico en la firma del método.
Alguien puede explicarme que hago/entiendo mal?
Gracias y disculpar la pregunta (y código) de novato... dudo que a nadie más le sirva esta duda. Saludos coders!

```
//Calcular la posición de X número fibonacci usando recursividad.
//0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,...
public class Recursivo6 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int posicion = fibonacciRecursivoPosicion(0,1,1,0,8);//n1,n2,n3,posicionBusqueda,numeroABuscar
        System.out.println("La posición del n Fibonacci 8 es: "+posicion);
    }
    public static int fibonacciRecursivoPosicion(int n1, int n2, int n3, int posicion, int fibonacci){
        if (fibonacci != n3){
            System.out.println("dentroIf"+posicion);//para debug
            n1=n2;
            n2=n3;
            n3=n1+n2; 
            fibonacciRecursivoPosicion(n1,n2,n3,posicion+1,fibonacci);
            return posicion;
        } else {
           System.out.println("fueraIf"+posicion);//para debug
           return posicion;
        } 
    }      
}
```

Salida código:

```
run:
dentroIf0
dentroIf1
dentroIf2
dentroIf3
fueraIf4
La posición del n Fibonacci 8 es: 0
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Lo que pretendo es que el retorno valga 'posicion' incrementado en el método, no el valor de del parámetro/atributo indicado en la firma.

Comment: Tienes un parámetro llamado `posicion` que nunca se modifica. Todos (los 2) tus *returns* son `return posicion;`. ¿Que tiene de inesperado el resultado?

Comment: @mrddr No, no soluciona la duda, ese enlace simplemente es una implementación de fibonacci.

Comment: Gracias Pablo, pretendo que el retorno sea el parámetro incrementado en el método. Fíjate que en la salida sí que se incrementa, pero no en el retorno.

Comment: Si lo que pretendes es que únicamente te devuelva la posición dentro de la secuencia de Fibonacci de un número dado he encontrado una forma distinta y más sencilla de implementar tu ejercicio: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-index-given-fibonacci-number-constant-time/

Comment: Gracias Mrddr por el código, pero quisiera entender que hago/entiendo mal del mio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parece que el error se encuentra en el `return posicion` dentro del bloque `if`. Según puedo comprobar, si cambias el `return` a la propia función recursiva, obtienes el resultado esperado:

```
public static void main( String[] args )
{
    int posicion = fibonacciRecursivoPosicion( 0, 1, 1, 1, 8 );//n1,n2,n3,posicionBusqueda,numeroABuscar
    System.out.println( "La posición del n Fibonacci 8 es: " + posicion );
}

public static int fibonacciRecursivoPosicion( int n1, int n2, int n3, int posicion, int fibonacci )
{
    if( fibonacci != n3 )
    {
        n1 = n2;
        n2 = n3;
        n3 = n1 + n2;
        return fibonacciRecursivoPosicion( n1, n2, n3, posicion + 1, fibonacci );
    }
    else
    {
        return posicion;
    }
}
```

Nótese que he cambiado también la `posicionBusqueda` para que coincida con la posición real del número en la secuencia.
Espero que sea lo que buscas, un saludo.

Comment: Genial!, si que funciona! Me cuesta entender porqué así sí que funciona, y no pasando la variable al retorno. Le daré unas vueltas más al 'coco' para ver si entiendo la diferencia. Muchísimas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Creo que te faltaba asignar la variable posicion dentro del método recursivo. Así creo que funciona

```
public class Recursivo6 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int posicion = fibonacciRecursivoPosicion(0,1,1,0,8);//n1,n2,n3,posicionBusqueda,numeroABuscar
        System.out.println("La posición del n Fibonacci 8 es: "+posicion);
    }
    public static int fibonacciRecursivoPosicion(int n1, int n2, int n3, int posicion, int fibonacci){
        if (fibonacci != n3){
            System.out.println("dentroIf"+posicion);//para debug
            n1=n2;
            n2=n3;
            n3=n1+n2; 
            posicion = fibonacciRecursivoPosicion(n1,n2,n3,posicion+1,fibonacci);
            return posicion;
        } else {
           System.out.println("fueraIf"+posicion);//para debug
           return posicion;
        } 
    }      
}
```

Comment: Sí señor! También funciona así! Entiendo que el problema es que tenía que asignar el retorno del método a una variable (creo). Muchas gracias!

Comment: Si te fijas, la solución de @F. López y la mía hacen lo mismo. Puedes devolver directamente el método o asignarlo a la variable posicion y devolver esta. La clave está en que el return sea de un modo u otro el método recursivo.